# Need for thread.sleep() when playing a sound array using DirectSoundOut

Tags: c#, winforms, naudio

```
dso = new DirectSoundOut(Guid.Parse(AudioOutDevice));
var ms = new MemoryStream(soundArray.ToArray()))
{
    IWaveProvider provider = new RawSourceWaveStream(ms, new WaveFormat());
    dso.Init(provider);
    dso.Play();
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
}
```

I am able to play sound array through desired output device using the above code, and i am unable to hear the sound if there is thread.sleep. But I am unable to understand the reason for using thread.sleep. Can any one let me know the reason for thread.sleep()

Comment: That code doesn't even look like it would compile.

Comment: Is `dso.Play();` a non blocking call? it could be that `ms` gets disposed before the sound is played, the Sleep keeps it from going out of scope. Maybe check for a blocking version of play and use that instead of Sleep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `Play` is not blocking. It simply starts playback. So you must keep `dso` alive until playback ends or you have stopped it manually.

You can use code like this if you want to block yourself (obviously only use this if your audio isn't infinitely long)

```
dso.Play();
while (dso.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
{
    Thread.Sleep(500);
}
dso.Dispose();
```